# extern usage in Xcode4

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the following error

**Expected '{' before 'extern'**

while using a third party header file and it has the following code

```
extern NSString *const kXXXError;
```

Is the usage related to Xcode version as currently i am using Xcode4

```
extern NSString *const kDeviceErrorDomain;

extern const NSInteger kDeviceErrorCodeUnknown;

@class DeviceInsightInternal;

@interface Device : NSObject {
    DeviceInternal *_internal;
}

- (id)init;

- (NSString*)collect:(NSError**)error;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL allowsJavascript;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL privacyEnabled;

@end
```

Comment: can u provide a little bit more of a verbose code? like the entire .h so that we can get a bit more of a clue. Anyway, did you check that the @interface Blah: UIWhatever has a { that closes right after the ivars declarations

Comment: I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Looks like the problem is coming from before (maybe in one of your imports?).

Comment: Sorry to ask..I am new to objective C.... can u tell me what you are refering to with "has a { that closes right after the ivars declarations "

Comment: actually no imports ... its a third party header file given for usage in development..

Comment: i am using 3 party sdk .. instructions given to include .a file and the above header file ..so added these 2 into the project and had written my new class...to use functions declared here

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a scalar property to have a any sort of retain,assign,copy semantic, it will result in a compile error. You should change:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL allowsJavascript;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL privacyEnabled;
```

to

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsJavascript;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL privacyEnabled;
```